# Can't make hard link for mounted host file in LXD container

Tags: hardlink, lxd

I configed a host directory as a `disk` device in an unprivileged LXD container, like `/opt/app/var`, and I created a backup directory on container self filesystem, like `/backup`.

I used `rsync` to backup `/opt/app/var` files to `/backup` with hard link, but I got `Invalid cross-device link`

lxd container device config:

```
devices:
  var:
    path: /opt/app/var
    source: /opt/app/var
    type: disk
```

in container:

```
$ cat /proc/mounts | grep opt
/dev/sda2 /opt/app/var ext4 rw,relatime,stripe=64,data=ordered 0 0

$ cat /proc/mounts | grep "/ "
/dev/sda2 / ext4 rw,relatime,stripe=64,data=ordered 0 0

$ cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults    0 0
```

I found the mountpoint made by `lxd` is from `/dev/sda2`, and the root partition mountpoint is from `/dev/sda2` too, so it should be on a same device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a container issue.
You cannot create hard links across mount points, even when it’s the same device you (bind) mounted to different places in your FS hierarchy.

Try this on your system:

```
> cd /tmp/
> mkdir bar
> mkdir barm1
> mkdir barm2
> sudo mount --bind bar barm1 
> sudo mount --bind bar barm2
> cd barm1
> echo foo > foo
> ll ../barm2/ 

drwxr-xr-x   2 user users   4096 Jul 13 15:56 ./
drwxrwxrwt. 19 root root  147456 Jul 13 15:57 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 user users      4 Jul 13 15:56 foo

> cp --link foo ../barm2/foo2

cp: cannot create hard link '../barm2/foo2' to 'foo': Invalid cross-device link
```